# Iterate over a HashMap with multiple values per key

Tags: java, hashmap, iteration

I am currently learning sets and maps through university (still using Java 7).

They have given us a half finished to-do list app to complete. Currently the to-do list takes three String local variables to allow the user to state a job (aJob), a time to do it (aTime) and a date to do it (aDate).

The app also has an instance variable (today) that holds todays date.

I need to come up with a way to check the HashMap for any tasks that are due today. So I need to be able to query just the HashMap values attributed by the aDate local variable.

I know that to iterate Maps that I can place the keys or the values into a Set and then iterate over the set - not a problem. But if I use the values() method (within the Map class) to put these into a set - it places all three Strings per key into the set. I just want to move the aDate values into a set.

Any ideas?

I only seem to be able to find examples where the Maps have just a single Key and Single Value. This list has a single key and three values per key.

Any pointers would be good?

Kind Regards

Edit.....

Just thought I would add some code to help as there have been several different approaches - which I am all very greatful for. But not sure if they suit my needs....

The Job Class is constructed as such...

```
public Job(String aJob, String aDate, String aTime)
{
  Job = aJob;
  date = aDate;
  time = aTime;
}
```

I then create the map within the instance declarations for the To Do List class....

```
Map<Integer, Job> toDoList = new HashMap<>();
```

So I need to know the best way to iterate over this map, but it is only the Job attribute 'aDate' that is possibly going to hold the value I am after.

Not sure if that helps at all?

Kind Regards

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a `Map<K, Set<V>>` or a Guava `SetMultimap`. https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap

Comment: how about Map<aDate, Pair<aTime, aJob>>

Comment: So is aJob a `String` or a `Job`? Your instructions are very unclear and contradicting, "Creating a new class is not an option", but here you use `Job` as type for the values in your map. In fact, you constructor makes no sense at all, with `String aJob`, and then `Job = aJob`...

Comment: Apologies. Hopefully this clears things up. I cannot create any further classes, but we are given the class 'Job' to complete as part of the assignment. So we have the two classes in total. The job class and the to-do list class. The Job class is created first by taking three String arguments in the constructor. And it is the aDate String within the Job class constructor that I need to query to see if it matches todays date.

Comment: In that case, Toisen's answer is basically what you have to do. Just replace `Tuple` with `Job`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a class that holds all data that you need. E.g.
If you need something strange like `Map<String, Tuple<String, Integer, Date>>` just make a new class that holds the Tuple:

```
    class TupleHolder {
    private String firstValue;
    private Integer secondValue;
    private Date thirdValue;

    // get/set here...
}
```

and use it: `Map<String, TupleHolder>`

Comment: Unfortunately, we are given outlines as to what we can and cannot do for the assigment. Creating a new class is not an option. We need to try and stick to course material, but course material has only dealt with placing single Keys or Single values into Sets to iterate over them. We have not covered any Maps that have more than one values per key.

Comment: The way I see without using a new object is to make a map with linked list as second generics type, then get keys and iterate with them over map and it's values (embedded cycle).

Answer (score 1):

If really the only structure you're allowed to use is a Map where each key has 3 values (which is the case if I understand correctly), of which only one is a Date, you technically could do the following:

```
map.values()
    .stream()
    .filter(Date.class::isInstance)
    ...whatever else you want to do
```

The other suggested solutions are far better though, design wise.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use a custom class, as suggested by Toisen, maybe `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>` could do the trick for you.

I've added a sample of how to use it (as well as populating it with some random data)

```
public class FunkyMap {
    private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> jobs;

    // For random data
    private String[] job = {"EAT", "SLEEP", "FART", "RELAX", "WORK"};
    private String[] time = {"MORNING", "BEFORENOON", "NOON", "AFTERNOON", "EVENING", "MIDNIGHT"};
    private String[] date = {"FIRST", "SECOND", "THIRD", "FOURTH"};

    public FunkyMap() {
        jobs = new HashMap<>();

        // To populate some random data
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            String d = date[r.nextInt(date.length)];

            if(jobs.containsKey(d)) {
                HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> inner = jobs.get(d);
                String t = time[r.nextInt(time.length)];

                if(inner.containsKey(t)) {
                    inner.get(t).add(job[r.nextInt(job.length)]);
                } else {
                    List<String> s = Arrays.asList(new String(job[r.nextInt(job.length)]));
                    inner.put(t, new ArrayList<String>(s));
                }
            } else {
                jobs.put(d, new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>());
            }
        }

        // Actual iteration over date => time => jobs
        Iterator<String> i = jobs.keySet().iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            String iKey = i.next();
            HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> inner = jobs.get(iKey);

            System.out.println("Jobs scheduled for " + iKey);

            Iterator<String> j = inner.keySet().iterator();
            while(j.hasNext()) {
                String jKey = j.next();
                ArrayList<String> actualJobs = inner.get(jKey);

                System.out.println("\tAt " + jKey);

                for(String s : actualJobs) {
                    System.out.println("\t\tDo " + s);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FunkyMap();
    }
}
```

I took the liberty to assume that dates were unique, and time was unique per date, while a time could hold any number of jobs including duplicates. If the last assumption with jobs is not true, you could swap `ArrayList<String>` with `Set<String>`.